# How to apply Culture on property level like DataAnotation in MVC not global level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, culture

I only need to apply Culture on single TextBox control in its DataAnotation attribute, not for whole model

Languages  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx

In MVC5 C#

eg.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,DataFormatString = "ur-PK")]public string test { get; set; }
```

But it does not work.

Comment: You property is a `string` and it makes no sense to apply formats to a`string`! What are you trying to do? What is the value of the property and what is the expected output

Comment: i am trying to rendar textbox control with URDU language typing support

Comment: That's not what the `DisplayFormatAttribute` is for  - its for displaying numeric and `DateTime` properties in a particular format - so a `DateTime` which is today's date could be displayed as `11/5/2016` or `Sat 5 Oct 2016` etc

Comment: can you recomend any other datatype

Comment: `DataType` has nothing to do with language typing support.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about display your string in specific culture and you don't want to change language of everything (Just this textBox), you can create custom DataAnnotation like that

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string displayNameKey)
        : base(displayNameKey)
    {
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            // Get your string from db 
            // or load it from specific resource file 
            //(as your business) and return string;
        }
    }
}
```

But if you don't need all this, you can use the default Display and load your sting from Resource files